# Can't import urllib.request module in python 3

Tags: python-3.x, urllib, urlopen

I was executing a code from the book **Think Python** in **Python 3**. The code follows.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- encoding: utf-8 -*-

import urllib.request

conn = urllib.request.urlopen('http://thinkpython.com/secret.html')
for line in conn:
    print(line.strip())
```

When I execute this code in my machine's terminal, I got this following output.

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "secret.py", line 4, in <module>
>     import urllib.request
>   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 84, in <module>
>     import base64
>   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/base64.py", line 10, in <module>
>     import struct
>   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/struct.py", line 13, in <module>
>     from _struct import *
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_struct'
> Error in sys.excepthook:
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 63, in apport_excepthook
>     from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes
>   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
>     from apport.report import Report
>   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 12, in <module>
>     import subprocess, tempfile, os.path, re, pwd, grp, os, time
>   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 136, in <module>
>     import _posixsubprocess
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_posixsubprocess'
>
> Original exception was:
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "secret.py", line 4, in <module>
>     import urllib.request
>   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 84, in <module>
>     import base64
>   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/base64.py", line 10, in <module>
>     import struct
>   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/struct.py", line 13, in <module>
>     from _struct import *
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_struct'
> ```

I did this same code in Anaconda, and I got the correct output. Can anybody help me with this problem.

Comment: You appear to me missing all sorts of core modules that normally come with Python. Your Python installation seems *broken*.

Comment: Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: reinstall Python

Comment: apt-get install --reinstall python3